# How to put ImageViews next to each other

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a linear layout, in which lines with TextViews are. In the last line I'd like to include two ImageViews next to each other. My attempts with LinearLayout inside the RelativeLayout have not been successful yet. The pictures should have the same height (14dp) and a different width (one is rectangle, one is nearly square). How can I do this?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: You should post your code for clearity

Comment: Hey, please add snapshot of this, so i can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_left"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/leftImage" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/img_right"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/rightImage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hey, try using layout_weight for both the Imageviews**

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="15dip"
    android:paddingBottom="15dip"
    android:background="@drawable/dark_bg">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgLeft"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/left_img_icon" />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgRight"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" 
        android:marginLeft="8dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/right_img_icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I end having one picture on the left side of the view and the other on the right side of the view. What I want is to have them very close together or with 8dp between them. How to achieve this?

Comment: For your question's solution, just add android:marginLeft="8dip"